# Meaning of "waddle the straight and narrow the path" from a Batman comic

Tags: meaning-in-context

So long story short. The very known Penguin (a mob boss) has just left prison and he is meeting his love Dona probably for first time. Previously they have been in contact only via messages. So he is being released on parole because he is showing off to everyone that he is a different person. So in their discussion he makes a proposal of matrimony. And she says to him:

> And you must expect an affirmative response on one condition. You must, as we agreed in our many letters, **waddle the straight and narrow the path**!

I can't grasp the entire meaning of the bold part.

Comment: Use your dictionary.  *Waddle* is what a penguin does when it walks.  What does the dictionary (or Internet) say about *the straight and narrow path*?

Comment: Sometimes you stuck on the obvious.. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

To follow (or walk) the straight and narrow path is an expression meaning 'to get an honest job, lead an honest life, and not commit crimes, behave badly, etc'. Because she is addressing the Penguin, she says 'waddle' because that is the verb used for the ground motion of birds such as penguins, ducks, geese, and the like.

> the straight and narrow (path)
> a course of behaviour that is correct

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/straight-and-narrow-path)